# Show $AA^+$ is projection matrix onto the column space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show $AA^+$ is projection matrix onto the column space, where $A^+$ is the pseudoinverse.

Intro to Linear Algebra by Strang, doesn't seem to provide a proof of this.  My understanding is that a matrix is a projection if $P=P^2$.

Comment: You need to prove that $AA^+AA^+=AA^+$. Are there any standard pseudoinverse identities that would help with that?

Comment: If you care about the proofs, check out Carl Meyer's *Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra* as he does this very well.

Comment: @max_zorn can you tell me what page of that book the explanation is on?

Comment: Did Strang mention the identities $A^+AA^+ = A^+$ and $AA^+A = A$ in his text? These are two properties used to define a pseudoinverse. That's all you need to show that $AA^+$ is a projection.

Comment: I would like to point out that $AA^+$ is not just a projection.  It is an orthogonal projection.  That is, $AA^+$ is a Hermitian matrix.

Comment: @helios321 It is Example 5.13.3 Solution 2.