# Prove $AA^+$ projects onto the column space of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, projection-matrices, pseudoinverse

> Prove that $AA^+$ is the projection operator onto the column space of $A$

If $A$ has independent column vectors $A^TA$ is invertible and the projection operator onto the column space of $A$ is $P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$.

It is stated that, If $A$ has linearly independent columns, then the pseudoinverse of $A$ becomes $A^+=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ and $AA^+=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ is the projection operator on to the column space of $A$.

I know where the first statement comes from in the case for $A$ has independent column vectors, but how do I bring in the pseudoinverse into projection ?

**Note:** Similar question had been asked [Show $AA^+$ is projection matrix onto the column space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645507/show-aa-is-projection-matrix-onto-the-column-space) but the post failed to address the mentioned doubts.

$$
(AA^+)^2=AA^+AA^+=I\\
(AA^+)^T=(U\Sigma V^TV\Sigma^+U^T)^T=(U\Sigma \Sigma^+U^T)^T=U(\Sigma\Sigma^+)^TU^T=U(\Sigma\Sigma^+)U^T\\
=U\Sigma V^TV\Sigma^+U^T=AA^+
$$
$\implies AA^+$ is an orthogonal projector, but how do we show that it projects on to the column space of $A$ ?

**Is it enough ?**

If $y\in C(A)$, ie., $y=Ax$, for some $x$
$$PA=AA^+A=U\Sigma V^TV\Sigma^+ U^TU\Sigma V^T=U\Sigma\Sigma^+\Sigma V^T=U\Sigma V^T=A\\
Py=PAx=Ax=y$$

If $x\in N(A^T)$, ie., $A^Tx=0$ then
$$(I-P)x=(I-AA^+)x=x-AA^+x=x-$$

Comment: You showed symmetry, idempotence, and that $C(A)\subset C(P)$.  Instead of looking at the null space, just use the fact that for any $B$, $C(AB)\subset C(A)$.  This shows that $C(A)=C(P)$.  So you have a projection, and its image is exactly the column space of $A$, so it is projection onto the column space.

Comment: @Aaron So is it enough if I show that $C(A)=C(P)$ along with $P^2=P$(idempotence), in order to prove $P=AA^+$  projects onto the column space of $A$ ?

Comment: You need symmetry too, that $P^T=P$.  But you have that as well.  Idempotence + symmetry = orthogonal projection.  The only question left is where you are projecting onto.

Comment: @Aaron where you are projecting to is proved by $C(A)=C(P)$, right ?

Comment: Yes.  If $P$ is a projection, it is a projection onto $C(P)$.

Comment: Thanks, but you could have put that as answer though.

Comment: A projection which annihilates the complement of its image is orthogonal. Since $A:V\to W$ restricts to an isomorphism $(\ker A)^{\perp}\to{\rm img}\,A$ whose inverse (composed with the orthogonal projection $W\to{\rm img}\,A$ and inclusion $(\ker A)^{\perp}\to V$) is the pseudoinverse $A^+$. (This can be seen as the least-squares solution to $Ax=b$, i.e. the $x$ of minimal norm among those $x$ minimizing $\|Ax-b\|$.) From this definition it should be clear $AA^+$ orthogonally projects onto ${\rm img}\,A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix $P$ is an orthogonal projection if and only if $P^2=P$ (idempotence) and $P^T=P$ (symmetry).  The subspace that $P$ projects onto is its image/column space.  So if we wish to show that $AA^+$ is projection onto the column space of $A$, we need to show 4 things:

- $AA^+AA^+=AA^+$
- $(AA^+)^T=AA^+$
- $C(A)\subset C(AA^+)$
- $C(AA^+) \subset C(A)$

You proved the first 3 of these.  The fourth is a general fact: no matter what $B$ is (assuming the multiplication makes sense), $C(AB)\subset C(A)$.